# C++ Windows recv() doesn't return even if data are available

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock

I'm writing a C++ program. I need to receive a file and I'm using recv() function over a TCP socket to do that.

```
download_file() {
    while (left_bytes != 0 && !connection_closed) {
        if (left_bytes >= buffer_max_size)
            bytes_to_download = buffer_max_size;
        else
            bytes_to_download = left_bytes;

        if (request.conn->read_data(buffer, bytes_to_download))            
        {
            left_bytes -= buffer->get_size();
            temporary_file.write_data(buffer);
        } else connection_closed = true;

    }
}

read_data() {
    while (bytes_received < size && alive_) {
        bytes_read = recv(sock_, read_buffer, size, 0);

        if (bytes_read == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            delete[] local_buffer;
            throw SocketException(WSAGetLastError());
        }

       // the connection is closed
       if (bytes_read == 0) alive_ = false;
       else {
           bytes_received += bytes_read;                    
           buffer->add(local_buffer, bytes_read);
       }

   }
}
```

The problem is that the recv never returns. It receives the whole file except for few KB and it freeze on the recv(). The buffer size is 1460.
I receive the file only if I print something to the console with cout every time the recv is called. Only in this case I receive the whole file.

Otherwise if I set as socket option the WAITALL and the client closes the connection after the file is sent, I receive the whole file.
Here's the code for the Client side that sends the file:

```
TransmitFile(file_request->connection_->get_handle_socket(), file_handler.get_file_handle(), file_request->file_size_, 65535, nullptr, nullptr, TF_USE_SYSTEM_THREAD)
```

**EDIT**

Here's how I send and read the file size between the Client and Server.

```
std::stringstream stream_;
stream_.str(std::string());
// append the file size
const __int64 file_size = htonll(GetFileSize(file_handle_, nullptr););
stream_ << ' ' << file_size << ' ';
```

Then I use the send to send this string

Here's how I read the file size

```
// Within stream_ there is all the content of the received packet
std::string message;
std::getline(stream_, message, ' ');
this->request_body_.file_size_ = ntohll(strtoll(message.c_str(), nullptr, 0));
```

**EDIT**

I cleaned up the code and I found out that read_data() is obviously called once and I was updating the buffer variable wrongly. Hence I was tracking the size of the content within the buffer in a wrong way which make me call the recv() once more.

Comment: *How* do you know there are data available to be received? Perhaps you should consider non-blocking sockets?

Comment: I saw through out wireshark that the whole file is sent and the ACK for each packet sent is received. As far as I know the TransmitFIle return true only if the whole file has been transmitted and received on the other end.
Anyway I uptaded the question with more line of codes I forgot at first

Comment: you probably try to receive more bytes that the other side is actually sending and that why recv never returns.

Comment: Indeed, you probably iterate once to many, and call a `recv` after you actually received all your data. Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially good would be to use a debugger to step through your code line by line while monitoring the variables and their values.

Comment: The TransmitFile receive as parameter the bytes to send: file_request->file_size_
This is the same value that I send to the server so that It knows how many bytes to receive (left_bytes is settled in this way).
The file_request->file_size_ value comes from: GetFileSize(file_handle_, nullptr); windows function

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would exclude that because everything works fine if I call std::cout before or after the recv call.
Anyway thanks for the link. It's useful in any case.

Comment: It seems like the last remaining data are stored within some OS buffer and never returned back.

Comment: You send the size to the peer how? And read it how?

Comment: @EJP I use an  sstream object.  I'll edit the answer with that info.

Comment: So you are probably losing some of the initial file data into that object. Send it with `send()` and receive it with `recv()`.

Comment: How did you *receive* `message`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: `recv()` will block if there are no bytes left to read but the connection is still open.  So whatever you might say about what your code is doing, that *must* be what is happening here.

That could be for any of the following reasons:

- the sender lied about the size of the file, or did not send the promised number of bytes
- the file size was not interpreted correctly at the receiving end for whatever reason
- the logic that 'counts down' the number of bytes left in the receiver is somehow flawed

Trouble is, looking at the code samples you have posted, it's hard to say which because the code is a bit muddled and, in my eyes, more complicated than it needs to be.  I'm going to recommend you sort that out.

1. Sending the size of the file.

Don't mess about sending this as a string.  Send it instead in binary, using (say) `htonll()` at the sending end and `ntohll()` at the receiving end.  Then, the receiver knows to read exactly 8 bytes to figure out what's coming next.  It's hard to get that wrong.

2. Sending the file itself.

`TransmitFile()` looks to be a good choice here.  Stick with it.

3. Receiving the file and counting down how many bytes are left.

Take a closer look at that code and consider rewriting it.  It's a bit of a mess.

4. What to do if it still doesn't work.

Check with WireShark that the expected data is being sent and then walk through the code in the receiver in the debugger.  There is absolutely no excuse for not doing this unless you don't *have* a debugger for some reason, in which case please say so and somebody will try to help you.  The fact that logging to `cout` fixes your problems is a red-herring.  That just changes the timing and then it just happens to work right.

That's all.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your hints. I cleaned up the code and I found out that read_data() is obviously called once and I was updating the buffer variable wrongly. Hence the size of the content within the buffer was wrong which make me call the recv() once more.

Comment: OK, great stuff.  Moral: don't put up with messy code that you can't get your head around.  Its better to bite the bullet and fix it properly (although I have to admit, not all of my own code quite measures up in this department!).